# How does Jersey produce xml?

Tags: java, jersey

In the code below:

```
// This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }
```

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

how is jersey producing xml response from string? We are not mentioning how to marshall / unmarshall here.

Comment: Any returned object is serialized to xml using the accessors and modifiers i.e getters and setters.

Comment: I'm confused: The return string is already XML, so there is nothing for Jersey to do. Jersey is not producing XML; you already did.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `@Produces` annotation. From the [Jersey developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5n6/index.html):

> The `@Produces` annotation is used to specify the MIME media types of representations a resource can produce and send back to the client.

The annotation generates the logic to convert the string "response" into an XML, based on the MIME type `text/xml`.

Comment: Did OP change the question, because your answer doesn't seem to fit the question? There is no "conversion" of a `String` return type to a `text/xml` mime type *(well, except character encoding)*.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><hello> Hello Jersey</hello>"`, you are the one creating the XML. At this point you have generated the XML.

When you add `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)` to your endpoint you are simply saying that the response format you will be sending is XML. So the browser or whatever consumes your response will know what to expect.